# Remove extra space from image context converted from svg to pdf

Tags: context, svg

I have a Context text with a svg image. As expected, Context converts the image to pdf and includes it, but leaves a lot of empty room in the exported pdf. How do I get rid of this empty space?

mcve.tex:

```tex
\starttext
\externalfigure[card.svg][width=56mm, frame=on]
\stoptext
```

card.svg:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
  <rect fill="white" height="87" rx="10" ry="10" stroke="red" stroke-width="1" width="56" x="0" y="0"/>
</svg>
```

I call Context like this:

```bash
context mcve.tex
```

I think it uses Inkscape for the svg to pdf conversion; I use Inkscape 1.1.1 (3bf5ae0d25, 2021-09-20) on Linux.

Comment: ConTeXt LMTX provides a built-in converter from SVG to MetaPost, to use the converter add `conversion=mp` to the settings when you include the image, e.g. `\externalfigure[card.svg][conversion=mp]`.

Answer (score 1):

This may or may not be related to [issue 1017](http://tracker.luatex.org/view.php?id=1017). If I manually convert the `.svg` to `.pdf`, I get only the drawing exported:

```bash
for i in *.svg
do
    base=$(basename "$i")
    context_name="m_k_i_v_$base.pdf"
    inkscape \
        --export-filename="$context_name" \
        --export-type=pdf \
        --export-area-drawing \
        "$i"
done
```

Seems like my Context is a bit old; according to the [source code](https://source.contextgarden.net/tex/context/base/mkiv/grph-con.lua#l213) ConTeXt can already handle this. Unfortunately Ubuntu 21.10 still ships the old code that doesn't support Inkscape 1.1 yet, hence I'll stick with my workaround.